# How to export Application Insights Analytics data to Tableau?

Tags: azure, tableau-api, azure-application-insights

How can I link Applications Insights to Tableau so I can visualize my data?

Answer (score 2):

Application Insights supports continuous export (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry).

I expect Tableau to have some import capabilities. You probably will need to write an adapter from AppInsights data scheme to Tableau.

Comment: If you write this export to a csv or txt, Tableau can pick it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights also supports a REST API to query metrics, items (as ODATA), queries, etc.

https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Events

that might be better than paying extra to duplicate (export) all your telemetry?

Comment: But AI retains data only for 90 days. If we need the backup, then we need to enable continuous export to blob storage and use that as source.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-data-retention-privacy